# POST 2 Guid parameters to API with Angular

Tags: c#, angular, typescript, asp.net-core, asp.net-web-api

I Have made an API to follow a user. The method accepts 2 parameters which are two guids. The method:

```
// Follow user
[HttpPost]
public async Task<ActionResult<Guid>> FollowUser([FromBody] Guid user_gd, Guid user2_gd)
{
  if (ModelState.ErrorCount > 0)
  {
    return BadRequest();
  }
  var followedUser = await _user.FollowUser(user_gd, user2_gd);
  return Ok(followedUser);
}
```

The manager in API:

```
public async Task<bool> FollowUser(Guid user_gd, Guid user2_gd)
        {
            var followUserQuery =
                @"
                    insert into userbind(gd, user_gd, followed_user_gd, date_followed) 
                    values(@_gd, @_user_gd, @_followed_user_gd, @_date_followed)
                ";
            await PostQuery(followUserQuery, new
            {
                _gd = GenerateGd(),
                _user_gd = user_gd,
                _followed_user_gd = user2_gd,
                _date_followed = DateTime.Now
            });

            return true;
        }
```

The API request in Angular (service):

```
followUser(followed_user, user_gd): Observable<any> {
    try {
      return this._http.post<any>(this._apiUrl + "FollowUser", { "user2_gd": followed_user, "user_gd": user_gd }, this.httpOptions);
    } catch (e) {
      console.log("POST error: ", e);
    }
  }
```

The component:

```
followUser(gd) {
    console.log(gd);
    this._userService.followUser(gd, localStorage.getItem("gd")).subscribe(
      res => {
        console.log(res);
      }
    )
  }
```

The variables and everything works right now but I am getting this error everytime:\

**"Cannot deserialize the current JSON object (e.g. {"name":"value"}) into type 'System.Guid' because the type requires a JSON primitive value (e.g. string, number, boolean, null) to deserialize correctly.\r\nTo fix this error either change the JSON to a JSON primitive value (e.g. string, number, boolean, null) or change the deserialized type so that it is a normal .NET type (e.g. not a primitive type like integer, not a collection type like an array or List) that can be deserialized from a JSON object. JsonObjectAttribute can also be added to the type to force it to deserialize from a JSON object.\r\nPath 'user2_gd', line 2, position 15."**

Does someone know how to fix this or expierences the same problem? Please reach out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try creating class with required fields and accepting it in your `FollowUser` action as a parameter:

```
public class FollowUserParams
{ 
    public Guid user_gd { get; set; }
    public Guid user2_gd { get; set; }
}

// Follow user
[HttpPost]
public async Task<ActionResult<Guid>> FollowUser([FromBody] FollowUserParams p)
{
   ... use p
}
```

Also see Andrew Lock's [post](https://andrewlock.net/model-binding-json-posts-in-asp-net-core/) on model binding in ASP.

Comment: So in my manager I will have to fill the class you created and return that?

Comment: @AntonioSk You can just pass values to it like `await _user.FollowUser(p.user_gd, p.user2_gd)`

Comment: Where should I fill the class?

Comment: @AntonioSk nowhere. ASP will do it for you when your `FollowUser` action in controller will be invoked. It will try to bind the parameters you pass in the request body (in the angular) to this class (that what is failing for you now as far as I can see).

Comment: Bro thanks so much!!! I didn't understand you at first but it works right now thanks man!

Comment: @AntonioSk was glad to help!